# Why is my weather app slow to update?

Tags: 8.0, apps

My weather app is usually quite inaccurate. It always feels like it's hours behind.

Currently, the app reports this:

[image: Screenshot]

But if I head over to [AccuWeather](http://www.accuweather.com), where the app is supposedly getting its data, it reports the accurate and real-time weather.

[image]

I've tried clicking on the <kbd>Current</kbd> and <kbd>Refresh</kbd> buttons many times. I can see that it reloads the data, but it's still out-dated.

**How can I make my weather app more real-time?**

Comment: The Bing Weather app for the desktop doesn't use AccuWeather as it's primary source, so do you have a reference for the mobile app doing so?

Comment: Is it connected to the internet to allow it to update?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I looked at the [credits section](http://i.imgur.com/O2Ry4p3.jpg) under settings.

Comment: @karancan Yes I have internet access. It does **eventually** update, but it isn't anywhere near real-time. It's usually 4 - 6 hours out of date.

Comment: Even if it's not AccuWeather, it was most certainly **not** -1° at the time.

Comment: Have you set the "Update data only while on WiFi" option?

Comment: For me, the current conditions match those from the Windows 8 app

Comment: No, I haven't selected that option.